# Problem setting lat and lng variables on Google maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I put lat on the row[2] and put lng on the row[3] in my DB
when I run the code below, the Google map is not visible.
However, when I change variables like 
 latitude = 25.3444
 longitude = 131.0369
it works

I want to know what the problem is with the code below.

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
if($row[0] == $num){
    $lat = $row[2];
    $lng = $row[3];
    }
}

?>

<script>    
latitude = '<?= $lat ?>';
longitude = '<?= $lng ?>';

function initMap() {
var uluru = {lat: latitude, lng: longtitude};
var map = new google.maps.Map(
  document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 7, center: uluru});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
}
</script>
```

Comment: define `$lat` and `$lng` before while loop

Comment: What errors do you get in the javascript console?  I get `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: longtitude is not defined` with the posted code (because you have a typo, `longtitude` should be `longitude`).  If I fix that, I get two errors: `InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number` and `InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`, because they are strings, not numbers.

Answer (score 0):

define `$lat` and `lng` before `while`

```
<?php
var $lat = '';
var $lng = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){    
if($row[0] == $num){
    $lat = $row[2];
    $lng = $row[3];
    }
}

?>

<script>    
latitude = '<?= $lat ?>';
longitude = '<?= $lng ?>';
```

Comment: Please add some explanations to your answer or it will be flagged as low quality.

Answer (score 0):

you only have to define the lat and lng to set those variables:
In php:

```
$lat = what ever you want;
$lng = what ever you want;
```

In js:

```
let lat = what ever you want;
let lng = what ever you want;
```